# Screensaver shows when resizing a window with WindowManager

Tags: android, google-tv

i've got (i hope) a little issue doing some development for Google TV

what I am trying to do is I want to be able to show a small window in the bottom-right corner, This is fine.. The issue is i'm unsure how to get rid of the screen saver in the background

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_eyece_box_window);

     final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(               
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,               
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                         | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                         | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE); 
     params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
     params.width = 300;
     params.height = 500;
     this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

}
```

So really what i want the application to do is show above the stack

[image: Image of the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my best solution for this is to basically scrap it and build it on a custom dialog box

Answer (score 3):

Add android.permission.WAKE_LOCK to the manifest and invoke the PowerManager:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
        | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "tag");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

Comment: what would that allow me to do?

Comment: it pokes the user activity timer and makes the screensaver go away.

Comment: Ah ok, well from what i have read last night my previous approach will not work as i cannot have two activities on the one screen at once, which is what i previously wanted to do... Therefore i am thinking my current approach would be better by doing it as a dialog instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an overlay on the live TV signal then you can use this intent to get the live TV to show:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tv://passthrough"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The main idea was to get It to pop up above everything I'll try this though, thanks

Comment: yeah, unfortunately that doesn't do anything